# mysql query issue more left joins

Tags: php, mysql

MY mysql query is as below :

```
SELECT 
    `pickupreq`.*, 
    `pinP`.`Pincode` as PinP, 
    `pinD`.`Pincode` as PinD, 
    `tslots`.`StartTime`, 
    `tslots`.`EndTime`, 
    `usr`.`FirstName`, 
    `usr`.`LastName`, 
    `staff`.`FirstName` as sFirstName, 
    `staff`.`LastName` as sLastName, 
    `ord`.`Id` as OrderId, 
    `ord`.`NoOfItems`, 
    `ord`.`NoOfItemsReadyForDelivery`, 
    `ord`.`CurrentStatus`, 
    `ord`.`TotalAmount`, 
    `ord`.`PickupSignature` 
FROM 
    (`PickupRequests` as pickupreq) 
    LEFT JOIN `Users` as usr ON `usr`.`Id` = `pickupreq`.`UserId` 
    LEFT JOIN `Users` as staff ON `staff`.`Id` = `pickupreq`.`AssignedTo` 
    LEFT JOIN `TimeSlot` as tslots ON `tslots`.`Id` = `pickupreq`.`TimeSlotId` 
    LEFT JOIN `Orders` as ord ON `ord`.`PickupRequestsId` = `pickupreq`.`Id` 
    LEFT JOIN `UserAddresses` as addrpick ON `addrpick`.`Id` = `pickupreq`.`PickupAddressId` 
    LEFT JOIN `Country` as countryP ON `countryP`.`Id` = `addrpick`.`CountryId` 
    LEFT JOIN `State` as stP ON `stP`.`Id` = `addrpick`.`StateId` 
    LEFT JOIN `City` as cityP ON `cityP`.`Id` = `addrpick`.`CityId` 
    LEFT JOIN `Pincode` as pinP ON `pinP`.`Id` = `addrpick`.`PincodeId` 
    LEFT JOIN `UserAddresses` as addrdeli ON `addrdeli`.`Id` = `pickupreq`.`DeliveryAddressId` 
    LEFT JOIN `Country` as countryD ON `countryD`.`Id` = `addrdeli`.`CountryId` 
    LEFT JOIN `State` as stD ON `stD`.`Id` = `addrdeli`.`StateId` 
    LEFT JOIN `City` as cityD ON `cityD`.`Id` = `addrdeli`.`CityId` 
    LEFT JOIN `Pincode` as pinD ON `pinD`.`Id` = `addrdeli`.`PincodeId` 
WHERE 
    `pickupreq`.`PickedUpStatus` = 'Yes' 
    AND `pickupreq`.`Status` <> 'CancelRequest' 
    AND `ord`.`CurrentStatus` NOT IN ('Completed', 'Delivered')
```

above table not gets record whos value is NULL and 0 in Orders table's PickupRequestsId.
what should i do to also get **NULL** and **0** value records from Orders table's PickupRequestsId column

Comment: Note that `LEFT JOIN x... WHERE x...` is the same as `INNER JOIN x...`. In other words, move the last line up to the JOIN clause for that table.

Answer (score 1):

```
     LEFT JOIN `Orders` as ord ON `ord`.`PickupRequestsId` = `pickupreq`.`Id` 
+-->
|    LEFT JOIN `UserAddresses` as addrpick ON `addrpick`.`Id` = `pickupreq`.`PickupAddressId` 
|    LEFT JOIN `Country` as countryP ON `countryP`.`Id` = `addrpick`.`CountryId` 
|    LEFT JOIN `State` as stP ON `stP`.`Id` = `addrpick`.`StateId` 
|    LEFT JOIN `City` as cityP ON `cityP`.`Id` = `addrpick`.`CityId` 
|    LEFT JOIN `Pincode` as pinP ON `pinP`.`Id` = `addrpick`.`PincodeId` 
|    LEFT JOIN `UserAddresses` as addrdeli ON `addrdeli`.`Id` = `pickupreq`.`DeliveryAddressId` 
|    LEFT JOIN `Country` as countryD ON `countryD`.`Id` = `addrdeli`.`CountryId` 
|    LEFT JOIN `State` as stD ON `stD`.`Id` = `addrdeli`.`StateId` 
|    LEFT JOIN `City` as cityD ON `cityD`.`Id` = `addrdeli`.`CityId` 
|    LEFT JOIN `Pincode` as pinD ON `pinD`.`Id` = `addrdeli`.`PincodeId` 
|   WHERE 
|    `pickupreq`.`PickedUpStatus` = 'Yes' 
|    AND `pickupreq`.`Status` <> 'CancelRequest' 
+--- AND `ord`.`CurrentStatus` NOT IN ('Completed', 'Delivered')
```